# XML Node and Child Nodes

Tags: java, xml

```
header = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
Element headerElement = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName( "Header").item(0);
NodeList elementList = headerElement.getElementsByTagName( "*" );
for( int index =0; index < elementList.getLength(); index++ ){
    Node element = elementList.item(index);
    System.out.println( element.getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent() ); // Statement A          
    System.out.println( element.getTextContent()); // Statement B
```

Both Statement A and Statement B are printing the same output.

What does it means, every node is a child node for itself??

And the input XML is

```
<Header>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag2>2</tag2>
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    <tag4>4</tag4>
</Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTextContent()` returns returns the text content of this node ***and its descendants***.

Statement A executed at `tag1` returns the text node below (`1`)

Statement B executed at the same place gets the child nodes of `tag1` (a list with one text node), selects the first (only) text node and displays its text value.

In this instance they are the same thing.

Comment: Bullseye! So can u tell me, how to check whether , there are no tags under it. I mean something that does not come between < >

Comment: Examine the node type of each node in the returned list. Look in the Javadoc for `org.w3c.dom.Node` for a list of node types.

Comment: @madhairsilence: What's the bigger picture here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I encounter this, i need to print "No Child Nodes " <tag1>1</tag1>, becoz I just have a text "1" not a "tag"

Comment: When you get to `tag1` examine all of its child nodes and group them by type. If you have only `TEXT_NODE` and possibly `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` nodes (i.e. no `ELEMENT_NODE` nodes) then that matches your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of `Node.getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29), for a node type of `ELEMENT_NODE`:

> concatenation of the textContent attribute value of every child node, excluding COMMENT_NODE and PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE nodes. This is the empty string if the node has no children.

Whereas for a text node, the return value of the method is just `nodeValue`, i.e. the text of the node.

So yes - calling this on an element with a single child node which is a text node *will* give you the same results as calling it directly on that text node. But in other cases you'd get different results. For example, if you had an element like this:

```
<tag>1<break />2</tag>
```

there would be two child text nodes and one child element node, and the result would be "1 2" (or possibly "12"; I'm not sure how spacing works in this concatenation off-hand, but you can check).

It's not a matter of a node "containing itself" - it's simply a matter of the definition of what this method does.

Comment: @madhairsilence: I don't know what you mean. I've explained exactly why your code behaves the way it does: the implementation follows the documentation.